# Fit webpage in Android WebView

Tags: android, webview, xamarin-studio

I have a webpage in ASP.NET and now I am creating an Android application using **Xamarin** through which user can access this webpage. I am using `WebView`.

Problem I am facing is that the content of webpage is not fitting in `WebView`, probably it seems a duplicate question but I did not got a proper answer in previous posts.

My layout code is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <WebView 
        android:id="@+id/webview1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and `MainActivity` code is

```
namespace DsclQuery
{
    [Activity (Label = "DsclQuery", MainLauncher = true, Theme = "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        WebView webview;

        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
            webview = FindViewById<WebView> (Resource.Id.webview1);
            webview.LoadUrl ("http://www.dsclsugar.com/QuerySecure");
            webview.SetWebViewClient (new dsclQueryWebViewClient());
            webview.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            webview.Settings.UseWideViewPort = true;
            webview.Settings.BuiltInZoomControls = true;
        }
    }
```

[image: screen shot of AVE]

How can I do this ?

Comment: In the web page include viewport meta tag.

Comment: @karthick I tried `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">` 
but still problem is same

Answer (score 1):

### Try This code:

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.loadUrl("your url");

int scale = (int) (100 * webview.getScale());
webview.setInitialScale(scale);

webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

Its android native code, I think you can understand !

I hope it will useful. Thank you.

Comment: Nope, still problem is same