# Zoom controls in Android Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, webview, zooming

I want to add zoom controls in my android app for webview using xamarin tool. I have added controls but when I zoom, my content goes out of page. I want to make zoom within page. Here is my code which I am using :

```
        web_view = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webview);
        web_view.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
        web_view.Settings.SetSupportZoom(true);
        web_view.Settings.BuiltInZoomControls = true;
        web_view.LoadUrl("Any URL"));
```

Comment: What do you mean "my content goes out of page"? I just tried your code and it worked as expected on my end.

Comment: I mean that when I zoom in , content should be in the same window but I have to drag left or right to see the full content.

Comment: here is something which I am asking
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22928732/fit-webpage-in-android-webview

Comment: Using zoom control to zoom in a page， the page will goes out of webview as default. And the for  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22928732/fit-webpage-in-android-webview this issue I think he need to set the meta data of the html page, make the page adapts to the phone screen `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>`

Comment: Is there any way, after zoom in page do not goes out of webview ?

Comment: I am using xamarin(C# .net)

Comment: @Umair As noted your code worked as expected with a web page I tried. Do you get the issue with all web pages?

Comment: @jgoldberger thanks friend, I used "textzoom" which fulfilled my requirements.